# Prove or disprove $(A-B)\cup(B-C)=A-C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove or disprove the following statement: 
>   $(A-B)\cup(B-C)=A-C$

I know is true, but can I use a typical element argument to prove it?
I need to split into 2 parts

1. $(A-B)\cup (B-C)\subseteq A-C$
2. $A-C\subseteq (A-B)\cup (B-C)$

then I am not sure how to continue.
Is it start by $x\in (A-B)\cup (B-C)\implies x\in(A\cap \overline{B})\cup (B\cap\overline{C})$ ?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: "I know is true ... " How could it possibly be true? Eg take A small and B big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim is false. Take for example $B=\emptyset$ and $A=C\not=\emptyset$ then
$$(A-B)\cup (B-C)=A\quad \text{and}\quad A-C=\emptyset.$$